Pogo tv. Open a door! show
I am from India and when I was 15 years old (6-7 years ago), I used to watch a short (5-10 minute) show (like pat and stan or Pingu) on a channel called Pogo. The main crux of the show was showing the lives of kids across the globe.
It basically starts with a boy/girl opening a door(usually of their house) and going about their usual work and ends with them going back into their home and closing the door. If my memory serves me right, I think the show was called Open a door with Pogo but Google refuses to show any relevant links to the same.
NOTE: It is not an animated show. The people were real and each episode was shot in a new country. 

Pat and stan & Pingu are examples of short shows, they do not reflect the content of the show I am searching for in any way.
